# how to cross some column in Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have data schema like `{col1:chararray,col2:int,col3:bag{}}`

e.g.

```
{a,1,{d,e}}

{b,2,{c}}
```

I want to have an output like

```
{a,1,d}

{a,1,e}

{b,2,c}
```

I think it is kind of like having a cross over some columns, but I don't know how to achieve the same ? Maybe there are some other methods to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use to ToBag function and Flatten

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (col1:chararray,col2:int,col3:bag{});
B = FOREACH A GENERATE col1,col2, FLATTEN(TOBAG(col3));
```